# Clarification on strcpy

Tags: c, null, c-strings, strcpy

I am currently learning C via edube.org and came across something that didn't quite agree with my observations when I run the code in Code blocks.

For example: edube.org says that The invocation:

strcpy(string, "Alice has a cat");

fills the array **string** with the string **Alice.**

I initially thought (just going by the above statement in edube.org) that this is probably because the space after "Alice" may have been considered a null character '\0' marking the end of the character.  But this does not seem to be the case. I am just looking for clarification to convince myself that edube.org is indeed incorrect.

Comment: `strcpy` will copy all characters up to and including the terminating null character `'\0'`.  Spaces are treated the same as printing characters.

Comment: If it was `strcpy(string, "Alice\0 has a cat");` then it would copy up to and including the null character embedded in the string literal.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland could you please point me to a better website to use. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation. Glad  I am not missing something, I also noticed though that if you are reading in text separated by spaces using scanf() it truncates before the first space, which is why fgets() is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you read wrong or the site is wrong.

```
strcpy(string, "Alice has a cat");
```

This fills the character array with the string `"Alice has a cat"`.

The null character (ASCII code 0) is a distinct character that cannot be typed from the keyboard directly. In C, it is represented by `\0` and is appended by default at the end of all string literals. It should not be confused with the space character (ASCII code 32), which is just a regular character.